# Elastic search combine aggregations

Tags: asp.net, elasticsearch, aggregation, nest

Currently query below removes duplicates on a single field - "name", but we need top_hits results for all fields:"name", "venueName", "venueTown". Is this possible to achieve within one query without sending 3 requests and setting "field" to be "venueName" and "venueTown"?

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "query": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "name"
      }
     ,
      "aggs": {
        "top": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
    "size": 0,
  "query": {

          "multi_match": {
            "query": "LAURA",
            "operator": "OR",
            "fields": [
              "name",
              "venueName",
              "venueTown"
            ]
          }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can write multiple aggregations with top hits.

```
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "LAURA",
      "fields": [
        "name",
        "venueName",
        "venueTown",
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "name": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "name"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "top": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "venue_name": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "venueName"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "top": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "venue_town": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "venueTown"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "top": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```